# GraphView Horizontal Date Labels unable to Line Break

Tags: java, android, simpledateformat, line-breaks, android-graphview

I am using the *GraphView* libary to draw graphs in an Android Application I am building.

The Graph uses dates for the x-axis. However, using `DateFormat` does not allow me to show on the horizontal label with a line break. Doing this will allow me to get more points and labels on the screen at a single time.

This is how the graph currently looks:

[image]

And this is how I want the labels on the graph to appear:

[image]

I am doing this by fetching the dates from a *SQLite* Database. I then convert them to Strings and store them in an array. The strings are then formatted to a `SimpleDateFormat` that contains a new line. I have debugged this several times and it is clear that each String in the array contains this new line. However, when setting the horizontal labels to this array of Strings it appears as it does in the first image not how I like it to be.

My code:

```
List<String> dates = new ArrayList<String>();
//getting the date Strings from the Sqlite Database
try {
    dates = db.getTimeDate();
} catch (ParseException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}

//Creates the line break to add into string
String newline = System.getProperty("line.separator");

//Create date format that contains the line break
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy"+newline+"HH:mm:ss");

//Iterate through arraylist formatting the string to new date format that contains linebreak 
for (int i = 0; i > dates.size(); i++) {
    String datad = dateFormat.format(dates.get(i));
    dates.set(i, datad);
}

final String[] _date = dates.toArray(new String[dates.size()]);

// make graphdata
List<GraphViewData> graphdata = new ArrayList<GraphViewData>();
for (int i = 0; i < dates.size(); i++) {
    graphdata.add(new GraphViewData(i, _time[i]));
}

GraphViewData[] _graphdata = graphdata
        .toArray(new GraphViewData[graphdata.size()]);

GraphViewSeries exampleSeries = new GraphViewSeries("", new GraphViewSeriesStyle(
        getResources().getColor(R.color.mathleteRed), 2), _graphdata);

GraphView graphView = new LineGraphView(this, "");
graphView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(320, 200));
graphView.addSeries(exampleSeries); // data
graphView.getGraphViewStyle().setTextSize(
        getResources().getDimension((R.dimen.graph_text_size)));
graphView.getGraphViewStyle().setNumHorizontalLabels(5);
graphView.setScrollable(true);
graphView.setShowHorizontalLabels(true);
((LineGraphView) graphView).setDrawDataPoints(true);
((LineGraphView) graphView).setDataPointsRadius(4);

graphView.setCustomLabelFormatter(new CustomLabelFormatter() {
    public String formatLabel(double value, boolean isValueX) {
        if (isValueX) {
            // Assuming only 7 total values here
            return _date[(int) value];
        } else
            return String.format("%.2f", value);
    }
});

graphView.setViewPort(0, 4);
graphView.getGraphViewStyle().setHorizontalLabelsColor(
        getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
```

Any help would be great. I know the problem is not with the *SQLite* Database as I have debugged and tested it several times.

Comment: I created a issue for this. https://github.com/jjoe64/GraphView/issues/191

Comment: Hey man, I actually came up with my own solution to this. Ill put it into the answer below and see if i can upload it to GitHub so you can implement it into your code if you wanted to. I also added some of other stuff that might be of use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the class **GraphView.java** the method **drawHorizontalLabels** is where the code must be added in order to line break. I have added another method in order to only line break if the horizontal labels is in date format, this way it wont break any labels that are not dates.

```
protected void drawHorizontalLabels(Canvas canvas, float border,
        float horstart, float height, String[] horlabels, float graphwidth) {

    // horizontal labels + lines
    int hors = horlabels.length - 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < horlabels.length; i++) {

        paint.setColor(graphViewStyle.getGridColor());
        float x = ((graphwidth / hors) * i) + horstart;
        if (graphViewStyle.getGridStyle() != GridStyle.VERTICAL) {
            canvas.drawLine(x, height - border, x, border, paint);
        }
        if (showHorizontalLabels) {
            paint.setTextAlign(Align.CENTER);
            if (i == horlabels.length - 1)
                paint.setTextAlign(Align.RIGHT);
            if (i == 0)
                paint.setTextAlign(Align.LEFT);
            paint.setColor(graphViewStyle.getHorizontalLabelsColor());


    //this is where I have added code.

            if (HorDates == true) {
                String[] Text = horlabels[i].split("\\s");

                canvas.drawText(Text[1], x, height - 25, paint);
                canvas.drawText(Text[0], x, height - 15, paint);
            } else {
                canvas.drawText(horlabels[i], x, height - 25, paint);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However this will only work if the date is formatted with a space between the Date and the Time like so:
**11/12/14 01:21:40**

This way the code will split the label text into two strings at the space and then draw them separately one under another.

there is also a simple set HorDates method:

```
public void isHorLabDates(boolean _HorDates) {
    this.HorDates = _HorDates;
}
```

the horizontal labels now print in the canvas like so:

**11/12/14**

**01:21:40**

Answer (score 0):

Now it is possible, thanks to @appsthatmatter (jjoe64) and @LDSDev, just use `"\n"` in `DateFormat`.

You can even use the `DateAsXAxisLabelFormatter` as in the [Use dates as labels](http://www.android-graphview.org/dates-as-labels/) example:

```
graph.getGridLabelRenderer().setLabelFormatter(new DateAsXAxisLabelFormatter(
        getActivity(), new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy"+"\n"+"HH:mm:ss")));
```

Tested with *GraphView 4.2.2*.

---

> **Alternatively**, I recommend you try the next option to show the labels with a certain angle of inclination. In some case, it allows to display the labels in a more compact and elegant way:
>
> ```
> graph.getGridLabelRenderer().setHorizontalLabelsAngle(135)
> ```